# jQuery element show only a part of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have various `a` elements that i get with this jQuery selector:

```
$("#toc").find("li a")
```

If one element text is "first second" (and all elements' text are two words divided by a space) I want to show only the first word, in this example the element's text should be `first`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the second word in a `span`, and hide that:

```
$('#toc li a').html( function(i, h) {
    var words = h.split(/\s/);
    return words[0] + ' <span>' + words[1] + '</span>';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V7aEt/3/).

With the CSS:

```
#toc li a span {
    display: none;
}
```

To address situations where there might be more than two words:

```
$('#toc li a').html( function(i, h) {
    var words = h.split(/\s/);
    return words[0] + ' <span>' + words.slice(1).join(' ') + '</span>';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V7aEt/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a text filter to each element:

```
$("#toc").find("li a").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().split(' ')[0];
});​
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7aEt/2/)**

Keep in mind that I have not accounted for cases where there could be only one word or no words.